# Descomponer número entero en factores primos con Javascript

Tags: javascript

Necesito que muestre el proceso como en la imagen, intente hacer algo pero no funciona

```js
function decomp(n) {
            let arr = {},
                ans = [];
            for (let i = 2; i <= n; i++) {
                let idx = i;
                for (let x in arr) {
                    while (idx % x === 0) {
                        idx /= x;
                        arr[x]++;
                    }
                }
                //if (idx > 1) arr[idx] = 1;
            }
            for (let x in arr)(arr[x] === 1) ? ans.push(x) : ans.push(x + "^" + arr[x]);
            return ans.join(" * ");
        }
```

```html
<p class="op"></p>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tu algoritmo para descomponer en factores primos puede mejorarse.

El algoritmo que se usa es el que todos hemos usado en clases de matemática en secundaria:

1. Si N es par, se divide entre 2 y se apunta el resultado.
2. Si N es impar, se intenta dividir entre el siguiente número primo impar (3, 5, 7,...) hasta que obtengamos una división exacta y se anota el resultado
3. Se aplica nuevamente el paso 1 o 2 al resultado de la división anterior, y se comienza de nuevo.

Debemos establecer un mecanismo para ir almacenando la cantidad de veces que aparece nuestro factor primo en la descomposición.

Ya tenemos los ladrillos necesarios para construir nuestra función.

Una forma en que podemos escribir la función sería la siguiente:

```
function descomponerEnPrimos(N) {
    var arr = []; //aqui almacenamos los factores temporalmente
    var resultado = N;// el primer valor que usaremos es N
    while(resultado > 1) { // 'resultado' irá variando hasta hacerse 1
        for (var i = 2; i<= N; i++) { // vamos realizando pruebas
            if(resultado % i === 0) {
                resultado = resultado / i; //actualizamos el valor de resultado
                arr.push(i);
                break; // salimos del bucle for
            }
        }
    }
    var factores = []; // aqui almacenaremos los factores de forma mas legible
    var factor = arr[0]; // almacenamos el primer valor
    var cont = 1; // instanciamos la cantidad de veces que aparece el primer elemento
    if (arr.length > 1) { // si hay más de 1 elemento en el array
        for(var i = 1; i < arr.length; i++){
            if (factor !== arr[i]) { // si el factor cambia, ya no se repite más, podemos almacenarlo
                factores.push({factor: factor, seRepite: cont});
                factor = arr[i]; // establecemos el nuevo factor
                cont = 0; // inciamos el contador en cero, en la siguiente linea aumentará 1
            }
            cont++; // si el factor se repite, aumentamos el contador, si estaba en cero se aumenta a 1
        }
        factores.push({factor: factor, seRepite: cont}); // almacenamos el último factor encontrado
    } else { // en caso que N sea primo, solo tiene un factor
        factores.push({factor: factor, seRepite: cont});
    }
    return factores;
}
```

Con esta función ya tenemos una forma de calcular la descomposición en factores primos de cualquier número entero positivo.

Una forma de implementar esta función para mostrar el resultado sería la siguiente:

```js
function descomponerEnPrimos(N) {
    var arr = []; //aqui almacenamos los factores temporalmente
    var resultado = N;// el primer valor que usaremos es N
    while(resultado > 1) { // 'resultado' irá variando hasta hacerse 1
        for (var i = 2; i<= N; i++) { // vamos realizando pruebas
            if(resultado % i === 0) {
                resultado = resultado / i; //actualizamos el valor de resultado
                arr.push(i);
                break; // salimos del bucle for
            }
        }
    }
    var factores = []; // aqui almacenaremos los factores de forma mas legible
    var factor = arr[0]; // almacenamos el primer valor
    var cont = 1; // instanciamos la cantidad de veces que aparece
    if (arr.length > 1) { // si hay más de 1 elemento en el array
        for(var i = 1; i < arr.length; i++){
            if (factor !== arr[i]) { // si el factor cambia, ya no se repite más, podemos almacenarlo
                factores.push({factor: factor, seRepite: cont});
                factor = arr[i]; // establecemos el nuevo factor
                cont = 0; // inciamos el contador a cero, ya que se aumentará a 1 en la siguiente linea
            }
            cont++; // si el factor se repite, aumentamos el contador
        }
        factores.push({factor: factor, seRepite: cont}); // almacenamos el último factor encontrado
    } else { // en caso que N sea primo, solo tiene un factor
        factores.push({factor: factor, seRepite: cont});
    }
    return factores;
}

function calcular() {
    //instanciamos el elemento de salida
    var salida = document.getElementById('salida');
    //capturamos el entero
    var entero = Number.parseInt(document.getElementById('entero').value);
    // si el valor no es un numero valido salimos
    if(Number.isNaN(entero)){return;}
    // llamamos a la funciona que calcula los factores primos
    var factoresPrimos = descomponerEnPrimos(entero);
    // construimos el string del resultado
    var resultado = entero.toString() + " = ";
    for(var i = 0; i < factoresPrimos.length; i++) {
        //usaremos el 'tag' <sup> de HTML
        resultado += (factoresPrimos[i].factor).toString() + "<sup>" + (factoresPrimos[i].seRepite).toString() + "</sup>" + (i < factoresPrimos.length - 1 ? " x " : " x 1");
    }
    // escribimos la salida
    salida.innerHTML = resultado;
}
```

```html
<form style="margin: 1rem">
  <label for="entero">Introduzca un número entero:</label><br>
  <input type="text" id="entero" name="entero" />&nbsp;&nbsp;
  <button id="boton" onclick="calcular()" type="button">Descomponer</button><br>
  <p id="salida"></p>
</form>
```

Espero que esta respuesta sea lo que estabas buscando.